Tokens in Word Document are Not Merged
I am trying to create a printable form which will have contact details already printed on it.
If I create the form in Civi, I cannot insert logos or shapes, but all the tokens merge correctly.
If I create the form in Word, only the Contact ID will merge and the other tokens remain unchanged.
There seem to have been a lot of questions on these lines over the years, but no answers. Have there been any bug fixes or progress since then?

Is your goal to send a link eg with checksum to someone so that they can then print out the form with their own details already filled in? Or just for the admins to visit such a form and see it prefilled with contact X's details, to then be able to print?

The aim is to be about to print a form with each person's details so that all they have to to is tick a box, rather than fill in their details. It's for printed forms.

as a workaround, would a csv import and then a 'mail merge' (if that is what Word calls it) to produce the forms work for you.

or does this offer a way of doing it in civi? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/48645/96

Exporting to mailmerge would be the answer for bulk mailings, but it would be good to be able to produce it for an individual on request, for which a mailmerge would be a bit elaborate,

I'll look into the search action designer; thanks,
